# getting timeout error during commiting large files on svn

Tags: eclipse, apache, svn

We are using SVN with ubuntu 14.04 and eclipse subversion and apache. It works fine when we commit small files. But when we try to commit large file, it gives following error.
    **eclipse error:**
    Some of selected resources were not committed.
    Some of selected resources were not committed.
    svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: E175002: Commit failed (details follow):
    svn: E175002: can not read HTTP status line
    svn: E175002: PUT request failed on '/svn/test/!svn/wrk/953b88fa-5601-0010-8146-c3b0661fb4b6/trunk/*/TokenManagerImpl.java'

```
apache error.log 

[Mon Sep 05 19:12:18.533736 2016] [dav:error] [pid 26083:tid 140002512074496] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 182.75.153.50:56725] Timeout reading the body (URI: /svn/test/!svn/wrk/953b88fa-5601-0010-8146-c3b0661fb4b6/trunk/*/TokenManagerImpl.java)  [408, #0]
[Mon Sep 05 19:12:18.533851 2016] [dav:error] [pid 26083:tid 140002512074496] [client 182.75.153.50:56725] mod_dav_svn close_stream: error closing write stream  [500, #185004]
[Mon Sep 05 19:12:18.533876 2016] [dav:error] [pid 26083:tid 140002512074496] [client 182.75.153.50:56725] Unexpected end of svndiff input  [500, #185004]

Below is apche timeout configuration (apache.conf)
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 250
KeepAliveTimeout 20
LimitRequestBody 0

Below is reqtimeout.conf 
<IfModule reqtimeout_module>
       RequestReadTimeout header=200-400,minrate=5000
       RequestReadTimeout body=1000,minrate=5000
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that invalid `RequestReadTimeout` configuration is the root cause. You should not put a special timeout for `body`.

Apache Subversion transfers commit data as request body and it's size depends on the size of commit. Therefore, with the config you currently have, all commit operations that take more than ~1000 seconds will fail for your users.

Comment: still getting same error after removing RequestReadTimeout body params

Comment: @anilchandgude remove `RequestReadTimeout` directives completely and test again, please.

Comment: yes. I have removed it completely . But issue is still there

Comment: @anilchandgude and you have already restarted Apache service?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else ends up here with:

svn commit via http

Large binary file ~80MB.

Transmitting file data .

svn: E185004: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E185004: Unexpected end of svndiff input

Change the apache2 reqtimeout.conf file for the header as well.

(The symptom is the svn commit will croak after 40 seconds...)

```
    RequestReadTimeout header=200-400,minrate=500
```

Fixed it for me. "Your mileage may vary..."

Comment: where should this config to be provided